# kendo Grid DataSource with OData format = json

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, odata

We've *asp.net web api* odata enabled service which supports variety of OData formats such as ***application/json;odata=fullmetadata***

This services is working great with ***WCF Data Service Client*** and ***JayData***

But our response seems not to be compatible with our **kendo grid dataSource**

I've investigated the response and here is the difference:

The demo of kendoUI site which is working fine has following response:

```
"__count": "91"
```

And the response content type is: `text/javascript;charset=utf-8`

You can see the sample of kendo UI demo at:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html

And here is our response:

```
"odata.metadata":"http://localhost:2452/odata/$metadata#VehicleGroups","odata.count":"29","value":[
```

And the response content type is: `application/json; odata=fullmetadata; charset=utf-8`

Can I have a ODataMediaTypeFormatter that generates needed format?
Or is there any solution to make KendoDataSource works with our current response?
Any other solutions are appreciated.

Note that we've enabled OData for KendoDataSource with `type: "odata"`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because KendoUI still communicates in the OData V2 format and your server is operating with OData V3.

To solve this problem you can use V2 on your server side or refine how the KendoUI transport processes the response by adding the following configuration to the data source object:

```
            schema: {
                data: function (data) {
                    return data.value;
                },
                total: function (data) {
                    return data['odata.count'];
                }
            },
```

So kendo grid will understand that ***total*** will be at *totalCount* section of the response instead of **"__count"**